# Read INSERT output from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCategory]
  @Name nvarchar(100)
AS  
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Category]([Name])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.CategoryId, INSERTED.[Timestamp]
    VALUES (@Name)
END
```

And I call it like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[InsertCategory] @Name= @Name
```

I would like to know what the id of inserted Category is (it is output in insert statement). It is written to the output, but I can't figure out how to assign it to a variable without modifying stored procedure. In C# I can use command.ExecuteReader and I get it, but I do not know how to get it in SQL Server.

I also cannot use SCOPE_IDENTITY as we have our own system of generating ids.

Comment: You already used the `OUTPUT` clause. What are you asking? Isnt' that `CategoryID` the value you need? Why would you need `SCOPE_IDENTITY` when you already return the ID and timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- count use a temp table as well 
-- syntax: CREATE TABLE #t(CategoryId int,[Timestamp] datetime)
DECLARE @t table(CategoryId int,[Timestamp] datetime)

INSERT @t(CategoryId, [TimeStamp])
EXEC [dbo].[InsertCategory] @Name= @Name

SELECT CategoryId, [TimeStamp]
FROM @t
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. I knew about this but I couldn't realize I can use another type than Timestamp for a timestamp :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Declare a table and insert output into it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCategory]
  @Name nvarchar(100)
AS  
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @Result AS TABLE (
         CategoryId int,
         TimeStamp varchar(50)
     )
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Category]([Name])
   OUTPUT INSERTED.CategoryId, INSERTED.[Timestamp]
   INTO @Result(CategoryId, TimeStamp)
   VALUES (@Name)

   SElect * from @Result
END
```

Comment: You are not reading the output parameters from the stored procedure. You are reading it within the stored procedure. Otherwise it seems fine